# Hybris Commerce Cloud Data clean-up

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

In our system we have disabled all the Generic Audit logs by setting the flag to “**audit.product.enabled=false**” and as noticed we have “**products1sn**” table name which is occupied with 170GB. Since last cloud migration we are not auditing any entry but  is it possible to clear this table in commerce. Cloud any one please suggest how to clear data safely from this table and should not impact on current system.

Similar we have other tables with huge data is there, not sure which one we can clear without any impact on current system.

[image]

is there any impact on system after clearing “**products1sn**” ? can you please share how to clear data with safe mode and without impacting existing system.

Comment: Hi team, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

in my experience we removed the oldest ones with a Beanshell acting directly on the DB with a TRUNCATE TABLE. Audits are just a simple "changelog" table, I don't see any issue on removing them, since it usually has to be done for GDPR reasons.

Please check the documentation for more [info](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/3e2b8491449d43b391eb1ce9c73cbb7f.html?locale=en-US&q=audits)